# HCI stack for Atmel

Tags: bluetooth, atmel

I am developing a portable device embedding BT communication to connect it with a computer. I found out that to reach high bitrate (115ks/s) I need to implement the HCI stack. Is it needed or can it be done someway else?

At present, I'm oriented in choosing the [Atmel SAM3S](http://www.atmel.com/products/at91/sam3s.asp?family_id=605), do you know whether there is some kind of library available for this family?

Comment: What is HCI in this context?  Human–computer interaction?

Comment: USB Host Controller Interface

Comment: HCI = Host Controller Interface, but it is not tied to USB.  It can be accessed via an type of serial bus (UART, SPI, etc.) -- http://www.bluetooth.com/English/Technology/Works/Pages/Architecture__Host_Controller_Interface_HCI.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in [uClinux](http://www.uclinux.org/) (3S's doesn't have MMU), since [there is BT support in it](http://docs.blackfin.uclinux.org/doku.php?id=bluetooth_over_uart).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I just posted a question about this possibility! http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13439/linux-on-a-mcu-boards-and-examples

Answer (score 2):

BTStack is a portable BSD licensed stack:

http://code.google.com/p/btstack/

Comment: is it suited also for MCUs with no operating system?

Comment: It looks like it's primarily targetted at iPhone, but is very portable.

Comment: @stef It was made to run on a Cortex-M3 (there is a news item in the home page) so I guess the answer is "yes".